# He is fired. / He was fired

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

When do you use "He is fired." in this case? If it happened on this day?

-- **X is going to be our new manager.** -- **But what happened to the previous one?** -- **He is fired. / He was fired.**

Comment: I would only use it when recounting a story in the present tense.  _At the beginning of 'Sliding Doors', Gwyneth Paltrow's character is fired from her job._

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Is "He was hired" the best choice here?

Comment: Simple Present *He is fired* would never occur in the cited context. But actually, Present Perfect *He **has been** fired* would be much more likely than Simple Past *He **was** fired*, given that the ex-manager's *current status* is the primary focus of the utterance.

Comment: By 'here', do you mean the sentence you quote in bold type using _fired_? I would use _He was fired [yesterday]_ or _He has been fired [today]_.